# Views Image Field - Field Collection Show Only one Image

Tags: views, entities, media

I have a view that displays an image from a list of image [field collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection). However, it is showing all the images from the collection. I only want the first image to be shown and hide the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module provides the option to select -in the field's settings- how many items you want to render for multi value fields. See the image below:

[image]